# store php multidimensional array in localstorage

Tags: php, javascript, local-storage

I'm building a site where a user can use the site and input data.  However to save their data, they need to log into my site (using facebook connect).  The data that they input is stored in a php multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
$order = array();
$order[] = array('rank'=>'1', 'day'=>'Tues');  // This $order[] has input inputted several times by the user
// I haven't included all the code because it's big, all that's really needed is to see the structure of $order
```

My question is, how do I convert the php multidimensional array into javascript and then how do I store it onto localStorage using localStorage.setItem() so that once they've logged in with facebook connect I can use that data?  Is this the best way of going about it or should I be doing something else?

```
<?php
require_once 'src/facebook.php';
$order = array();       
$order[] = array('rank'=>$column, 'day'=>$day); 
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'user_about_me,email'));
?>

<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function fblogin() {

                var fk = "<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>";
                // What do I do here to convert $order into javascript?
                // What do I do here to store converted $order onto localStorage()  
                window.location = "<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <INPUT type="image" src="img/fb.png" onclick="fblogin()" />
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: I think you have to use `var fk = "<?php echo json_encode($order); ?>";`

Comment: local storage is not supported in old browsers. Are you sure you want to use it ?

Comment: Can't you just put each cell of array in one item?

Comment: I thought php sessions were expired/reset once the user left the site?  Technically the user is leaving the site when they go to facebook to log in and then automatically come back to my site as it happens within the same browser window.

Comment: Ok, I checked out php sessions and got it working.  Was very easy even for multidimensional arrays.  session_start();

$_SESSION["order"] = $order;   To retrieve:                    $neworder = array();
$neworder = $_SESSION["order"];

Comment: Edit, I was actually right the first time.  I made a mistake with the second comment, I was already logged on facebook when I was testing it therefore when I was logging in, it wasn't redirecting to facebook.  Once I logged off facebook and tried it from scratch it didn't work.  Once you leave the page/website it wipes $_SESSION even if you don't close the browser.  Looks like I'm back to using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode() your array, send it to the client, and localeStorage the serialized array.